# Taylor expansion of $((H+\epsilon A)^T R^{-1} (H+\epsilon A))^{-1} (H+\epsilon A)^T R^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, taylor-expansion

I have seen a kind of contradiction in a paper and  I decided to rewrite the  equations... Could you please help me to be sure about what I am doing...

Let us define $H^\dagger \triangleq (H^TH)^{-1}H^T $

One can show that the linear part of the taylor series of  $(H+ \epsilon A )^\dagger$ for small $\epsilon$ is $H^\dagger(I - \epsilon A H^\dagger)$.

Could you please help me on finding an approximation for the  linear part of the taylor series of $$((H+\epsilon A)^T R^{-1} (H+\epsilon A))^{-1} (H+\epsilon A)^T R^{-1}$$
for small epsilon?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mamal, rewrite correctly your question. With the new rules of the game, I find the following:

$f'(0)=-(H^TR^{-1}H)^{-1}(A^TR^{-1}H+H^TR^{-1}A)(H^TR^{-1}H)^{-1}H^TR^{-1}+(H^TR^{-1}H)^{-1}A^TR^{-1}$

Comment: The funciton is much more complicated than that! It is indeed $$f(\epsilon) = ((H+\epsilon A)^T R^{-1} (H+\epsilon A))^{-1} (H+\epsilon A)^T R^{-1}$$

Comment: Please note that the matrix $H$ is an $M\times N$ matrix. and $(H+eA)$ is not invertible generally!